# Comparing regression slopes in the case of paired data at multiple time points

Tags: regression, correlation, mixed-model

I have a group of indivdiuals and each individual has had two continuous variables measured (varaible A and Variable B) - both at timepoint 1 (baseline) and time point 2 (followup).
I would like to know if the relationship between the two variables variables changes with time, one way to do this is to compare correlations coefficients at the two timepoints e.g.

```
library(cocor)
baseline_r<-cor(datall4$A_baseline, datall4$B_baseline)
followup_r<-cor(datall4$A_followup, datall4$B_followup)
mixed1_r <- cor(datall4$A_baseline, datall4$A_followup)
mixed2_r <- cor(datall4$A_baseline,datall4$B_followup)
mixed3_r <- cor(datall4$B_baseline, datall4$A_followup)
mixed4_r <- cor(datall4$B_baseline, datall4$B_followup)
n <- nrow(mydata)
cocor.dep.groups.nonoverlap(baseline_r, followup_r, mixed1_r, mixed2_r, mixed3_r, mixed4_r,n)
```

I wondered what might be the best way to use a regression type model to examine this might be so that I could both potentially control for confounding variables and also get a measure of the change in the slope rather than just the goodness of fit?

Comment: "a measure of the change in the slope" Where is your slope?

Comment: By 'change in slope' I mean the difference between the beta values of the simple regressions at baseline (A_baseline ~ B_baseline) and followup (A_followup ~ B_followup). What I am unclear about is how best to account for the fact that the datapoints in those two regressions are linked